# Data structure to save chosen months of the year in SQL Server and display in WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, enums

I'm developing software with a C#, .NET, frontend in WPF and a SQL Server database to do some periodic invoicing and some clients don't want an invoice on specific months of the year. This invoicing is periodic and not related to the actual year. The invoice is generated from a 'Contract' object with certain parameters to create the periodic invoices.

When the user creates the contract, he should ideally see each month of the year with a checkbox to uncheck for when the contract shouldn't be invoiced. Now to save these user-chosen months I need some kind of data structure; at runtime and for SQL Server.

It sounds like I should use an **enum with flags**, but I'm quite stuck on this idea as it doesn't play nice with XAML (or I'm to inexperienced and can't get it to work). I could also just write a boolean per month in my contract-object but that seems like a stupid idea, or isn't it?

**Question**: what data structure should I use to save user chosen months of the year at runtime in SQL Server?

Edit: an example as clarification: a client can be a school and schools are closed in July and August (where I'm from). They shouldn't be invoiced for these months. Other companies can be closed on different months, so I can't just create a boolean 'IsSchool' and use that as filter.

Comment: Firstly, i am not sure if you understand the term `DataStructure` properly :( ... Anyway,what i can tell is that your goal can be achieved with a few lines of code :)

Comment: Well to me a couple of bits can be a datastructure. With 0xFFF0 being a 2 byte datastructure which would tell me that all the months of the year are selected. Is this a naive view?

Comment: And what do you mean by `enum doesn't play with XAML`? there's no relation in between them ,at least not in my knowledge :( .... Your basic steps would be to store the data somewhere in code like in some `List` or maybe a `Datatable` and easily pick which records to finally insert in database , that's all :)

Comment: The only reason to go with the set bits method (with or without an enum representation) is to save space.  So when choosing you have to ask if the complexity of using one option is worth the space savings of one small int column versus 12 bit columns.

Comment: After reading your edit, i would still stick to my previous comment that it is easy to achieve your goal and u can do this by following my second comment :)

Comment: To have 12 booleans seems like overkill and a code smell, but maybe I'm very wrong about this and indeed overthinking.

Comment: @MichelMichels It's the same thing with the option of having a one-to-many table for storing the months.  It's all about saving space.  One row of 12 bit columns versus n rows of two columns where n is the number of set months.  So, the savings is directly related to the average number of months that will be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd store them in a bridge table with two columns:  `User` and `Month`

Unless you've left some important detail out of your question, it sounds to me like you're overthinking this a bit.

Since not everyone seems to be able to picture what I am suggesting, here's a very short example:

```
Contract   Month
1          1
1          2
1          3
2          3
2          5
2          7
3          1
3          11
3          12
```

There could potentially be a lot of rows, but if the table is indexed it will always be plenty fast, no matter how long it gets.

Comment: Never heard "bridge table" before. What does this mean?

Comment: A bridge table is a table that exists solely to show a many-to-many relationship between two entities.  It's not a special type of table in SQL Server or anything like that, it's just a term that describes its purpose.

Comment: @UweKeim , bridge table is not a class actually, rather it is a term to explain ... like `MVVM` is nothing rihgt? rather it is a design architecture to explain how better and easier it would be to develop apps :)

Comment: Ok, you mean [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) .

Comment: I think Client and month ( a client might have numerous users ) .

Comment: @UweKeim You wouldn't necessarily need a many-to-many relationship since the "Ids" of the months should be static.  As in you shouldn't really need a table that tells you that 1 means January.

Comment: @juharr, well you wouldn't need a "Months" table, but the relationship is still many-to-many.   A user can have more than one month, and a month could have more than one user.

Comment: @TabAlleman No, without the Months table there is just a one-to-many relationship.  Many-to-Many requires 3 tables.  The rows in the lets call it UserMonth table would each map to exactly one User.

Comment: @juharr, No, the table I am suggesting would have more than one row per user.  It would have one row per User-Month combination.

Comment: For the sake of the argument, the months should be set on the contract. So no users or clients are directly involved

Comment: @MichelMichels ok, then so my suggested table would have `Contract` and `Month` for its two columns.

Comment: @MichelMichels If I understand the use case of most contracts billing for all months except for a few that skip just a few months you might want to make the table hold the months to skip instead of the months to invoice for the greatest space savings.

Comment: @TabAlleman This seems like the most simple implementation.

Comment: @juharr that is correct.

Comment: Although I preferably fixed this with a 12 bit column (or 2 bytes as you can't have exactly 12 bits) mapped to a flag enum as I'm under the impression that this would be the most clean solution. But indeed, I am overthinking things.

Comment: @MichelMichels The trade offs are all between mapping complexity vs space savings and in the case of this option future expansion (if we ever have more than 12 months then this solution doesn't require DB changes).

Comment: You could combine the use of flags as I suggested in my answer with a single record per year on the database. Best of both worlds.

Comment: @MichelMichels Another reason to prefer this method over the others is if you need to run queries like finding all the contracts that bill in January.  This would likely result in the best performance while the bit flag would be the worst, requiring a full table scan.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly accomplish this using flags.

For the sake of explanation, let's say you collect the values of your check boxes into a list:

```
[Flags]
enum MonthsOfYear
{        
    January = 1,
    February = 2,
    March = 4,
    April = 8,
    May = 16,
    June = 32,
    July = 64,
    August = 128,
    September = 256,
    October = 512,
    November = 1024,
    December = 2048
}

public class Months
{
    internal static MonthsOfYear CalculateEnum(List<bool> checkboxes)
    {
        MonthsOfYear value = 0;
        var month = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            month = (i == 0) ? 1 : month * 2;
            if (checkboxes[i])
                value |= (MonthsOfYear)Enum.Parse(typeof(MonthsOfYear), month.ToString());
        }
        return value;
    }

    internal static List<bool> GetFlagsFromEnum(MonthsOfYear value)
    {
        List<bool> checkboxes = new List<bool>();
        var month = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            month = (i == 0) ? 1 : month * 2;
            checkboxes.Add((value & (MonthsOfYear)Enum.Parse(typeof(MonthsOfYear), month.ToString())) != 0);
        }
        return checkboxes;
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
List<bool> checkboxes = new List<bool>() { true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false };
Output("Original: ", checkboxes);
var selectionValue = Months.CalculateEnum(checkboxes);
var unpackedCheckboxes = Months.GetFlagsFromEnum(selectionValue);
Output("Unpacked: ", unpackedCheckboxes);        

checkboxes = new List<bool>() { true, true, true, false, false, false, true, true, true, false, false, true};
Output("Original: ", checkboxes);
selectionValue = Months.CalculateEnum(checkboxes);
unpackedCheckboxes = Months.GetFlagsFromEnum(selectionValue);
Output("Unpacked: ", unpackedCheckboxes);
```

The output:

> Original: :
> True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False
>
> Unpacked: :
> True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False
>
> Original: :
> True,True,True,False,False,False,True,True,True,False,False,True
>
> Unpacked: :
> True,True,True,False,False,False,True,True,True,False,False,True

I whipped this out in a few minutes. What matters is the idea.